# Speech recognition in the cloud for audio longer than a minute

Tags: javascript, http

Speech recognition in the cloud for audio longer than a minute

Hello, I can't set up to have a transcript for long audio, now it only works for me with a length of less than a minute,
Below are the definitions:

```
function speechToText(file, googleApiKey){
  // Set the API endpoint URL and parameters
  var url = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=" + googleApiKey;
  var params = {
    "config": {
      "encoding": "LINEAR16",
      "languageCode": "he-IL",
      "sampleRateHertz": 8000,
      "audio_channel_count": 1
    },
    "audio": {
      "content": Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())
    }
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(params)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    "method": options.method,
    "contentType": options.contentType,
    "payload": options.payload,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });


  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(jsonResponse)
  var transcription = jsonResponse.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;

  Logger.log("Transcription: " + transcription);
  return transcription
}
```

I want a text longer than a minute to be transcribed as well.

Speech recognition in the cloud for audio longer than a minute